# Cant install VLC

Tags: package-management, 15.04, dpkg, dependencies, vlc

I am new to Ubuntu. while trying to update the vlc in order to be able to play certain videos, I screwed up and now im unable to install a new version of the VLC media player. while doing this, I was using Ubuntu 14.04. I thought it'll be fixed when I upgrade to 15.04 but it didn't help.
this is what I get when i try to install vlc through the terminal.

```
ricky@ricky-pc:~$ sudo apt-get install vlc
[sudo] password for ricky: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.0+git20160309+r58687+31+14~ubuntu15.04.1) but 2.2.1~trusty1 is to be installed
       Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not installable or
                libgles1
       Depends: libva-drm1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
       Depends: libva-x11-1 (>= 1.0.3) but it is not installable
       Depends: libxcb-composite0 but it is not installable
       Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) but it is not installable
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.2.0+git20160309+r58687+31+14~ubuntu15.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 2.2.0+git20160309+r58687+31+14~ubuntu15.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try to install VLC from software center, this message pops up, Package dependencies cannot be resolved.

Please me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Plz add more information http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121181

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get purge vlc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Answer (score 0):

for solving `unmet dependency` error, you can run these commands:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

then, try to install, update,...

Answer (score 0):

Type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-*
```

Answer (score -1):

Download the latest vlc deb file as per your ubuntu version from
http://pkgs.org/download/vlc

Install the package and fetch the repositories using:

> sudo gdebi downloadedPackageName.deb

If you already have it installed with missed dependencies, download and install the missing dependencies with

> sudo apt-get -f install

Comment: -1 No need to download the .deb file since VLC is already in the Ubuntu repositories.